# Chainlink VRF : Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to get a random number with Chainlink VRF,
So Hi have follow this demo step by step : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqZWariqh5s

here is what i've copied on Remix :

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

contract RandomNumberConsumer is VRFConsumerBase {
    
    bytes32 public keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;
    uint256 public randomResult;
    
    constructor() VRFConsumerBase(
            0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, // VRF Coordinator
            0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088  // LINK Token
        ) public
    {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
    }
    

    function getRandomNumber(uint256 userProvidedSeed) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee, userProvidedSeed);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness.mod(50).add(1);
    }
}
```

when i click on *getRandomNumber*, i always get this error :
**Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)**

and with the *fulfillRandomness*, i get this error :
**Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some `seed` number into the function, and then click it.

Also, be sure to [fund it with LINK.](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number)

Also, fulfillRandomness is only callable by the Chainlink VRF, so no worries on that part.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly... I'm just wondering if it is possible to get an array instead of a single number, by editing the contract ?

Comment: A random array? You could just put the number into an array after you get it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not passing the `userProvidedSeed` as an argument to `getRandomNumber()`

Try putting any number into the box beside the `getRandomNumber` method in Remix and then click on the method.

Also, fulfillRandomness is only callable by the Chainlink VRF, so do no worry about calling that function.